# Древовидная структура с parent в angular

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Есть такой json:

```
{
{
id: "1",
name: "cat1",
parentId: "null"
}
{
id: "2",
name: "cat2",
parentId: "1"
}

{
id: "3",
name: "cat3",
parentId: "2"
}
}
...
```

И html что-то вроде такого:

```
<li ng-repeat="...">
...
<li class="child">...</li>...
</li>
```

Собственно, нужно как-то это все выводить в древовидную структуру(вложенные категории). У меня из вариантов только генерировать готовый html и вставлять его туда. Может можно обойтись без этих костелей? кто что подскажет?

Answer (score 1):

Существует большое количество готовых JS-решений, решающих эту задачу.

Посмотрите, например, dynatree.

Подробнее:

- https://plugins.jquery.com/dynatree/

**Обновление 1.**

По поводу совместного использования Angular и jQuery:
это не всегда необходимо (и чаще всего, конечно же, нет), но если это необходимо, то это можно делать и в этом нет ничего противоестественного.

Этот вопрос довольно часто всплывает, и ответ на него неизменно один и тот же: если надо, то пожалуйста, почему нет.

Из [AngularJS FAQ](https://docs.angularjs.org/misc/faq):

> Does Angular use the jQuery library?
>
> Yes, Angular can use jQuery if it's present in your app when the
>   application is being bootstrapped. If jQuery is not present in your
>   script path, Angular falls back to its own implementation of the
>   subset of jQuery that we call jQLite.
>
> Angular 1.3 only supports jQuery 2.1 or above. jQuery 1.7 and newer
>   might work correctly with Angular but we don't guarantee that.

Comment: Если бы у меня был json который содержит в себе children, то без проблем, да. Видимо придется его перегенерировать на js

Comment: @shatal: да, см. обновление 1

Comment: @illlexial: перестроить такую структуру, это же одна строчка

Comment: shatal: есть решение сравнимое с dynatree для angularjs?

Answer (score 0):

В чем проблема отдавать сразу вложенные категории? Вряд ли они будут повторяться. Посмотрите на этот [пример](http://jsfiddle.net/0za2wxuy/). Здесь как раз отображение древовидной структуры, но вложенной, а не через parent.

Comment: Не могу повлиять на логику того что из бд отдается, у заказчика хранимые процедуры там. Пока что на js перестраиваю json и делаю обычными двумя ng-repeat